# How do I reset the format of a cell to the formatting set in table?

Tags: excel, vba

Preface: I figured out the answer while finishing up the question. I didn't see the question anywhere, so I'll post it anyway.

I've got a table style called Table Style 1.
I've used some VBA to format a cell if a date meets certain conditions:

```
'formatting for due dates
Select Case (DueDate.Value)
    Case ""
        DueDate.Value = "No Due Date"
        DueDate.Font.ColorIndex = 45
    Case Is > Date + 30
        With DueDate
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            .Font.ColorIndex = 53
        End With
    Case Else
        With DueDate
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            .Font.ColorIndex = 1
        End With
End Select
```

The problem is with the else case, Font.ColorIndex.
If the font color has been changed by a previous run of this sub, I need it to reset to the font color set in the table formatting.

I've tried color indexes 0 and 1. 0, because it worked for the interior.colorindex. 1, because the index of an unaltered cell in the table. Both just change the font color to black.

I have two potential ways to do this, but they could fail:

1. set the font color = the rgb/hex value of the text color set in the table formatting. If I eventually change the color of the font in the table formatting, this would have to be updated.
2. set the font color = the font color of the first cell in the table. If that cell's font color ever changed, it would mess up this formatting.

I think the property I'm looking for would be something like this:

```
With DueDate
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    .Font.ColorIndex = myTable.tablestyle.FirstRowStripe.font.colorindex
end with
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took some digging, but I found the property I needed.

```
With DueDate
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    .Font.ColorIndex = myTable.TableStyle.TableStyleElements(5).Font.ColorIndex
End With
```

Here is [more info on the TableStyleElements object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.tablestyleelements).
Here is the [XlTableStyleElementType enumeration list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xltablestyleelementtype).

I used enumeration # 5, xlRowStripe1.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer once the two-day time limit has passed.